# Why does IE give this error: Object doesn't support property or method isNaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error in IE 11:

> `Object doesn't support property or method isNaN`

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $total = $('#total'),
    $value = $('.value');
    $firstName = $('#firstname');
    $lastName = $('#lastname');
    $tour = $('#tour');
    $pledge = $('#pledge');
    $currency = $('#currency');
    $distance = $('#distance');
    $riders = $('#riders');

    $(':input').on('input change', function(e) {
        var total = 1;
        $value.each(function(index, elem) {
            if(!Number.isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)))
                total = total * parseFloat(this.value);
        });
        $total.val(total/10);

        $('#pledgefirstname').text($firstName.val());
        $('#pledgelastname').text($lastName.val());
        $('#pledgetour').text($tour.val());
        $('#pledgepledge').text($pledge.val());
        $('#pledgecurrency').text($currency.val());
        $('#pledgecurrency2').text($currency.val());
        $('#pledgecurrency3').text($currency.val());
        $('#pledgecurrency4').text($currency.val());
        $('#pledgetotal').text($total.val());
        $('#pledgetotal2').text($total.val());
        $('#pledgedistance').text($distance.val());
        $('#pledgeriders').text($riders.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Just use a standalone `isNaN` method without calling it from `Number` object: `if (isNaN(...))`.

Comment: Well, don't mix up `window.isNaN` and `Number.isNaN()`. I think the latter is an EcmaScript 6 feature.

Comment: OK thanks. What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: see why: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Number.isNaN

Comment: Some browsers already have `Number.isNaN`, but not all. Like @VisioN said, drop the `Number.`.

Comment: [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) is a *very* new and still experimental feature of the next JavaScript spec. It is not supported at all in IE. You've likely confused it with the global [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function, which has support in all browsers.

Comment: ...and FYI, this isn't a jQuery issue. `Number` is native JavaScript.

Comment: So what would that line look like if it were suitable for most modern browsers? Given I need to account for null values.

Comment: Do you see where you're calling `Number.isNaN(...)`? As everyone has explained, just use `isNaN(...)`.

Comment: That has broken other parts of my form. Estimated total does not calculate correctly now. http://antipodecycling.com/donate-support/sponsor-us/

Comment: I get no errors on that page. Are you sure you're not dealing with a cached version of the script?

Comment: ...go to the `Network` tab of the IE11 developer tools, and make sure the `Always refresh from server` button is selected.

Comment: If you select a tour, 'Estimated Distance' populates, add a pledge, say 1.00 'Estimated Total' does not calculate, like it did before I made this change. e.g. London to Paris at 1.00 should be $27. Could it be conflicting with the other js on the page? So calc in this eg should be 270 x 1 / 10

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50151/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-cookie-monster)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ## [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)
>
> This is an experimental technology, part of the Harmony (EcmaScript 6)
> proposal. Because this technology's specification has not stabilized,
> check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN#Browser_compatibility) for usage in various browsers. Also note
> that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject
> to change in future version of browsers as the spec changes.

It is still not supported by most of the browsers (including IE11).

You should use a standard [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) method instead:

```
if (isNaN( parseFloat(this.value) )) { ... }
```

Comment: It is, in fact, not supported in any version of IE.

Comment: That would seem to be implied.

Comment: Can you help me with the implementation of your solution? I'm not sure how to translate it. What goes in the curly brackets?

Comment: @square_eyes: Yikes dude, I think you're really over-thinking this.

Comment: @square_eyes Completely in the same way but without `Number.` part before `isNaN` call.

Comment: @square_eyes `if (isNaN(variable)) {alert('That is not a number')}`

Comment: Only one input field requires a number. I tried this solution and I get the warning when I change drop down selects.

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm simply trying to make the situation clearer to OP, given his/her level of experience with this.

Comment: @square_eyes: You get it after you've changed `Number.isNaN` to `isNaN`? Is the error in your console exactly as you show in the question? If so, then you have a capitalization issue. `isNan` vs `isNaN`.

Comment: @square_eyes: You must have fixed it when you posted the question, because the code shows the correct capitalization `isNaN`, while the error shows `isNan`.

Comment: I copied the code direct from my website, I never changed any capitalization. Using this solution breaks non numerical input fields on my form. The error was a typo. I will fix it.

Comment: It also breaks the calculation for "Estimated Total' http://antipodecycling.com/donate-support/sponsor-us/

Comment: OK fixed it thanks @cookiemonster for the chat. I dropped the !, silly me.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using ES6 with Babel in React. You can do like this:

```js
// pollyfills for older browsers
// core-js v2.x.x:
import 'core-js/es6/number'; 
// core-js v3.x.x:
import 'core-js/es/number';
```

Add dependencies in package.json for

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem except it was coming from React after it compiled, bundled, and minified.  To solve this, I redefined the `Number.isNaN`:

```
if (!Number.isNaN) {
  Object.defineProperty(Number, 'isNaN', {
    value: function(value) {     
      return value !== value;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: shoud be `if (!Number.isNaN) {` instead `if (!Number.isNan) {`